# How get list of data from Firebase into array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Swift. I know how to get a single piece of data from Firebase, but when I try to get a list of data into an array, I get no error or no data. Please help me.  I have been struggled with this for days now.
I want to add data from Firebase into array,
I have created json file with list of categories and imported in firebase.

My JSON file look like this:

```
 {
  "Category" : [ {
    "categoryId" : "1",
    "imageName" : "cat_001.png",
    "title" : "CAT"
  }, {
    "categoryId" : "2",
    "imageName" : "dog_001.png",
    "title" : "DOG"
  }, {
    "categoryId" : "3",
    "imageName" : "fish_001.png",
    "title" : "FISH"
  }, {
    "categoryId" : "4",
    "imageName" : "bird_001.png",
    "title" : "BRID"
  }]
}
```

Firebase database looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBXID.png)

Category class looks like this

```
struct Category {

    private(set) public var title: String
    private(set) public var imageName: String


    init(title: String, imageName: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
}
```

I use custom cell to show my data and here is my custom cell class

```
class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTitle: UILabel!

    func updateViews(category: Category){
        categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: category.imageName)
        categoryTitle.text = category.title
    }
}
```

And I use DataService class to get data, right now data is hard coded and its working fine.

```
  class DataService{
        static let instance = DataService()

// How to add data from firebase in here`?
        private let categories = [Category(title: "CAT", imageName: "cat_001"),
                                  Category(title: "DOG", imageName: "dog_001"),
                                  Category(title: "FISH", imageName: "fish_001")]

        func getCategories() -> [Category]{
            return categories

        }
    }
```

and finally here is my ViewController

```
class CategoriesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        categoryTable.dataSource = self
        categoryTable.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataService.instance.getCategories().count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell") as? CategoryCell {
            let category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateViews(category: category)
            return cell
        }else{
            return CategoryCell()
        }
    }
}
```

I am going to add more categories in the future.
 With hard coded data my app looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOpHu.png) and i want to achieve same result with data from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, just use an array of Category's for the tableview datasource:

`var tableData = [Category]()`

then in viewDidLoad, set up a firebase observer to update that array any time there are changes to the Category node in firebase:

```
ref.child("Category").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    var newTableData: [Category] = []

    for category in snapshot.children {

        let dict = category.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        let title     = dict["title"] as! String
        let imageName = dict["imageName"] as! String

        let newCategory = Category(title: title, 
                               imageName: imageName)

        newTableData.append(newCategory)
    }

    self.tableData = newTableData
    self.tableview.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @meggar, but i dont quit understand where to put this code and what to do. :(